# How do I get the top off this tap?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, plumbing-fixture

My kitchen tap has a ball joint at the top, which has sprung a small but steady leak - water drizzles out when the tap is turned off.

I presume the problem is either down to a perished rubber seal inside or a build up of limescale - but to be sure I need to get into the tap to look, and I can't figure out how to remove it.

There is an object like a rivet at the top rear of the tap

[image]

But I have no idea if that is an actual rivet, or something I can remove. If it does come off, will it need a specialist tool and if so, what might that tool be?

If I do succeed, I will need the correct replacement parts to fix the tap. I don't suppose anyone knows what model it might be?

[image]

Comment: Cutting torch. That is my go-to tool. You don't need the faucet anymore right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part that you think is a rivet is actually a plastic plug which can usually be sprung with a small pin or needle (cover the drain hole first). This reveals a screw which can be a slot head or a hex or allen key. Loosen this and the top handle lifts off revealing a large nut that holds the valve in position.